# How to display an underscore literal in math mode?

Tags: math-mode

I want to display the literal underscore character `_` in math mode because it is used in defining a variable name. I'm using the LaTeX parser that the Python Sphinx documentation generator uses, and in trying to parse a `\_` in math mode it gives this error:

```
System Message: ERROR/3 (/home/svc_citest/.hudson/jobs/build_doc/workspace/Research/Projects/doc/factors/crspAccruals/AccrualsImplementor.rst, line 83)

Syntax error: "\_"

Accruals = PreAccruals/AVG\_ASSETS
```

I would have thought that `\_` would work in math mode as it does in text mode, but I'm getting the error...

Here is the relevant doc page for Sphinx math mode: http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/math.html. It is mirroring AMS LaTeX, so if you need minimal working examples in which to insert the underscores, try there.

Comment: There are a multitude of questions referencing "[underscore on TeX.SE](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=underscore)" where you should find different ways of achieving an underscore. Otherwise you can try `\textunderscore` or `\rule{1ex}{.4pt}` but `\_` should work. Could you give a small example (a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)) that doesn't work for you?

Comment: Could you provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) please? For me also @ScottH.'s example compiles without errors

Comment: That is not a TeX error message. Is it your editor or some other parser that is getting confused?

Comment: The documentation suggests that you need a double backslash, perhaps try `\\_`: http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/math.html?highlight=latex

Comment: It is OK for me in texlive 2009 ( $ sth \\_ anotherthing $ )
But for more details check [this](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=underscore).

Comment: I'm using a raw-style Python string, so the double backslash is not needed. In regards to the MWE, it doesn't get much simpler than the example I did give. Just type `r""" .. math:: Accruals = PreAccruals/AVG\_ASSETS"""` into some `.py` file and compile the docs with Sphinx. It's basically just as much work as firing up an editor and compiling it with tex directly. Lastly, I'm looking for something that's not too verbose. `\textunderscore` is too verbose to have cluttering up a bunch of formulas in our code's docstrings.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The question states that it's using the Sphinx LaTeX parser. I've never encountered issues with it before, and have written probably thousands of lines of LaTeX dcoumentation in Sphinx, mostly in math mode. So I have a strong strong prior that the problem is not Sphinx.

Comment: Both `$\_$` and `\[\_\]` compile without errors in a minimal document latex wise.  The issue isn't with using `\_` in math mode w.r.t latex.

Comment: @EMS yes sorry I didn't recognise the name, so this question (like mathjax questions) is off topic for this site since it is a non-tex system parsing a texlike syntax, but in this case not exactly like Tex. So there is nothing to be done on the TeX side: \_ works in math mode in latex. as a workaround you might try the code in my (deleted) answer which is to use text mode for the multiletter identifiers `$\text{Accruals}=\text{PreAccruals/AVG\_ASSETS}$`

Comment: Based on [this post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69421/how-can-i-render-mathematical-formulas-in-python-sphinx) I disagree strongly with your opinion that it is off-topic. Notice that it was migrated *from* StackOverflow to this site. That would seem to endorse the idea that Sphinx syntax for rendering math through TeX is on-topic.

Comment: And notice from [the Sphinx doc pages](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/math.html): "The input language for mathematics is LaTeX markup. This is the de-facto standard for plain-text math notation and has the added advantage that no further translation is necessary when building LaTeX output." You are incorrect that it is TeX-like. It *is using* TeX.